# Create a new function which is not inherited from baseclass

Tags: c++, inheritance

Can I somehow create a new subclass method in C++ with the same name as a virtual one in base class, but stopping inheritance?

Let me explain it with some more details, consider this code:

```
#define L(m) std::cout << m << std::endl;

class A { 
public:
  virtual void func() { L("A::func"); };
  virtual void func2() { L("A::func2"); };
};     

class B: public A {
public:
  void func() { L("B::func"); }; //implements A::func
  void func2(){ L("B::func2"); }; //implements A::func2
}; 

class C: public A {
public:
  void func2() { L("C::func2"); }; //implements A::func2 
  void func() { L("C::func"); }; //meant to declare a new function but accidentally overrides A::func
};
```

I don't want to declare `func` as final in `A` (I know it would stop inheritance, but I need that for class `B`).

Also I want to call `C::func2` with `A`:

```
C c;
A* a = &c;
a->func2(); //must use C::func2 (standard inheritance)
a->func(); //must use A::func !!! (possible?)
c.func2(); //must use C::func2
c.func(); //must use C::func
```

Obviously I can rename C's `func` to something else but anyway, is this somehow achievable without completely abusing C++ norms?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want `func` to be used as virtual for `B`, but not for `C`? I don't think that's possible without dirty hacks involving RTTI.

Comment: maybe go a step back and consider that inheritance isnt the holy grail as they tried to make us believe. You do not have this "problem" when you use composition instead of inheritance

Comment: Yes, composition works for sure.

Comment: @Jarod42: code fixed

Comment: in the last snippt all comments say "use func2", is this a typo?

Comment: @idclev463035818: yes, corrected

Comment: What is the use case behind this? Normally when I use virtual methods, I really want them to be overidable by derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
class C: public A {
public:
  void func2() { L("C::func2"); };
  void func(int i = 0) { L("C::func"); };
};
```

The `C::func` is hiding the `A::func` one with a different signature. I got this result :

```
C::func2
A::func
C::func2
C::func
```

Instead of this with your code :

```
C::func2
C::func
C::func2
C::func
```